# Contravariance? Covariance? What's wrong with this generic architecture...?

Tags: c#, generics, architecture, covariance, contravariance

I'm having some problems setting up a command handling architecture.  I want to be able to create a number of different commands derived from ICommand; then, create a number of different command handlers derived from ICommandHandler;

Here's the interface and classes I have begun to define:

```
interface ICommand {}

class CreateItemCommand : ICommand {}

interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand {
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

class CreateItemCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateItemCommand> {
    public void Handle(CreateItemCommand command) {
        // Handle the command here
    }
}
```

I have a helper class that can create the appropriate type of command:

```
class CommandResolver {
    ICommand GetCommand(Message message) {
        return new CreateItemCommand(); // Handle other commands here
    }
}
```

And, a helper class that creates the appropriate handler;  this is where I'm having trouble:

```
class CommandHandlerResolver {
    public ICommandHandler<TCommand> GetHandler<TCommand>(TCommand command) {

        // I'm using Ninject and have an instance of an IKernel 
        // The following code throws an exception despite having a proper binding
        //    _kernel.GetService(typeof(ICommandHandler<TCommand>))

        var bindingType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());
        var handler = _kernel.GetService(bindingType);
        return handler as ICommandHandler<TCommand>; 
        // handler will be null after the cast
    }
}
```

Here's the main running method

```
CommandResolver _commandResolver;
HandlerResolver _handlerResolver;

void Run() {

    // message is taken from a queue of messages    

    var command = _commandResolver.GetCommand(message);

    var handler = _handlerResolver.GetHandler(command);
    // handler will always be null

    handler.Handle(command);
}
```

I can think of a few different ways to refactor the code that I'm sure would avoid the issue, but I found myself a bit perplexed by the problem and wanted to understand more of what was going on.

This design looks like it should work.

Comment: 1) `handler as CommandHandler<TCommand>;` why do you cast to the class, not the interface? 2) Why is that an `as` cast? The cast should never fail. | Replace it with `return (ICommandHandler<TCommand>)handler;`

Comment: Consider 1) replacing `ICommandHandler` by a delegate. 2) Consider making its `TCommand` type parameter an `in` parameter (contra-variant).

Comment: I've attempted to make TCommand contravariant but it has no effect.  In my understanding, that would only affect if I was passing the generic ICommandHandler type as an argument into a method, and, not the assignment problem that I suspect I'm having ie assign a CreateItemCommandHandler to an ICommandHandler<ICommand>.

Comment: Assigning `CreateItemCommandHandler` to `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` is only valid if you mark `TCommand` as contra-variant.

Comment: Please write a compilable example program and state what does not work. In your example you have contradictory claims. You can't have a null value in one line when the line before it threw an exception.

Comment: Slight nitpick and you might be doing it already - but you probably want to avoid naming things like `CreateItemCommandHandler` and name it after what it actually does. Not only does that read better, but that way when you need to add a second handler...well, you get the idea.

Comment: @CodesInChaos the code that is commented out throws the exception.  The code as-is returns null.  Which part of this does not compile?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer CreateItemCommandHandler is intended to handle the CreateItemCommand that has been sent.

Comment: @Sambo yup, and what happens when you have things that should handle the `CreateItem` command? For example a cache manipulation as well as your business logic, or a logger. `CreateItemHandler2`? Always name components after what they do, not how they're used

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I think the design here is meant to imply that each command type must have a single handler who's job is to execute that command. Other concerns such as cache manipulation or logging would not use the `ICommandHandler` mechanism but some other way, e.g. `ICommandHandlingInterceptor` or whatever. In the general sense you're right about naming things after their purpose rather than usage, but here the two are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Problem

Your problem is that you're mixing static types and runtime types: you're writing code that relies on having constructed generic types, but then you're invoking it with the base interface types.

Let's follow through your main flow:

Your `CommandResolver` always returns the static type `ICommand`. When you say:

```
var command = _commandResolver.GetCommand(message);
var handler = _handlerResolver.GetHandler(command);
```

The type of `command` is bound to `ICommand` and then gets passed to `GetHander`, which invokes `GetHandler<ICommand>`. That is, `TCommand` in this invocation is always bound to `ICommand`.

***This is the main problem here***. Since `TCommand` is *always* `ICommand`, doing:

```
_kernel.GetService(typeof(ICommandHandler<TCommand>))
```

...doesn't work (it looks for a `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` and the kernel doesn't have it); and even if it did work, you'd have to return it as `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` since that's the return type of the method.

By calling `GetHandler` without knowing (at compile time) the real type of the command, you lost the ability to use generics effectively and `TCommand` becomes meaningless.

So, you try to work around this: your resolver uses the command's *runtime type*(`command.GetType()`) to reflectively construct the type `ICommandHandler<SomeCommandType>` and tries to find *that* in the kernel.

Assuming you have something registered for that type, you'll get an `ICommandHandler<SomeCommandType>`, which you'll then try to cast to `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` (remember that `TCommand` is bound to `ICommand`). This of course won't work, unless `TCommand` is declared *covariant* in `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`, since you're casting *up* the type hierarchy; but even if it did, that's not what you want because what would you do with a `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` anyway?

**Simply put:** you can't cast an `ICommandHandler<SomeCommand>` to a `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` because that would imply that you can pass it any kind of `ICommand` and it'll happily handle it -- which is not true. If you want to use generic type parameters, you'll have to keep them bound to the real command type throughout the entire flow.

### Solution

One solution to this problem is to keep `TCommand` bound to the real command type throughout the resolution of both the command and the command handler, e.g. by having something like `FindHandlerAndHandle<TCommand>(TCommand command)` and invoking it by reflection using the command's runtime type. But this is smelly and clumsy, and for a good reason: *you're abusing generics*.

Generic type-parameters are meant to help you when you know, in compile time, the type you want, or what you can unify it with another type parameter. In cases such as these, where you don't know that runtime type, trying to use generics only gets in your way.

A cleaner way to solve this is by separating the context when you know the command's type (when you write a handler for it) from the context when you don't know it (when you try to generically find a handler for a generic command). A good way to do that is by using an "untyped interface, typed base class" pattern:

```
public interface ICommandHandler // Look ma, no typeparams!
{
   bool CanHandle(ICommand command);
   void Handle(ICommand command);
}

public abstract class CommandHandlerBase<TCommand> : ICommandHandler
  where TCommand : ICommand
{
  public bool CanHandle(ICommand command) { return command is TCommand; }
  public void Handle(ICommand command) 
  {
    var typedCommand = command as TCommand;
    if (typedCommand == null) throw new InvalidCommandTypeException(command);

    Handle(typedCommand);
  }

  protected abstract void Handle(TCommand typedCommand);
}
```

This is a common way to bridge the generic and non-generic worlds: you use the non-generic interfaces when invoking them, but take advantage of the generic base-class when implementing. Your main flow now looks like this:

```
public void Handle(ICommand command)
{
    var allHandlers = Kernel.ResolveAll<ICommandHandler>(); // you can make this a dependency

    var handler = allHandlers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.CanHandle(command));
    if (handler == null) throw new MissingHandlerException(command);

    handler.Handle(command);
}
```

This is also somewhat more robust in the sense that the actual runtime type of the command doesn't have to match one-by-one with the type of the handler, so if you have a `ICommandHandler<SomeBaseCommandType>` it can handle commands of type `SomeDerivedCommandType`, so you can build handlers for intermediate base classes in the command type hierarchy, or use other inheritance tricks.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation and code sample.  Makes sense what I was doing wrong now.  One thing I was trying to do (not mentioned in the original question) was to have one implementation of the ICommandHandler be able to handle a number of different commands.

I suppose implement another CommandHandlerBase as CommandHandlerBase<TCommand1, TCommand2> would be one way to do this.

Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: The nice part about using an untyped interface is that you can easily implement it to do anything you want -- handle two type of commands or a dozen (using e.g. a mapping between a command type and a handle delegate), or only handle commands with certain properties, etc. The abstract base class only helps you in the common case of building a handler for a specific type of command, but you don't have to use it at all.